# HardhatError: HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: missing token when deploying to Görli (Gorli/Goerli) testnet

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, hardhat, geth-debugging, hardhat-deploy

**Summary**

When I run `yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`, the following error is displayed in my terminal:

```
HardhatError: HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: missing token

    at parseJsonResponse (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/util/jsonrpc.ts:47:11)
    at HttpProvider._fetchJsonRpcResponse (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:206:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at HttpProvider.request (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:84:29)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider._getChainIdFromEthNetVersion (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/chainId.ts:33:17)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider._getChainId (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/chainId.ts:17:25)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider.request (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/chainId.ts:55:29)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
    at getSigners (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:45:20)
    at getContractFactoryByAbiAndBytecode (/home/parallels/workspace/hardhat-simple-storage/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:288:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**Details**

I am currently running a node by following the instructions outlined in `go-ethereum`'s README file:

```
INFO [TIMESTAMP] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/parallels/.ethereum/goerli/geth.ipc
INFO [TIMESTAMP] Generated JWT secret                     path=/home/parallels/.ethereum/goerli/geth/jwtsecret
INFO [TIMESTAMP] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://123.4.5.6:7890
INFO [TIMESTAMP] HTTP server started                      endpoint=123.4.5.6:7890 auth=true prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost
```

Next, I have added this to my `hardhat.config.js` as follows and already have `GOERLI_RPC_URL` defined in my `.env` file, and just for kicks, tried to adjust the URL to the different values shared above (i.e. tried the IPC endpoint, the HTTP endpoint with and without prepending `http://`).

```
const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 5,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.17",
}
```

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong here? `yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network hardhat` runs just fine, and I have yet to see a similar question asked regarding this specific issue.

Comment: Seems like a typo. Missing token is referring to any variable in ur deploy.js .
Please recheck ur deplo.js and also the solidity code. This doesn't seem to be a server side problem.